# Laravel Bind where in values on DB::select()

Tags: php, laravel-7, mysql-5.7

Here's the query that fetches the list of clients where id has values of `$client_ids`

Values of `$client_ids` is:

```
array:25 [▼
  0 => "PC00003"
  1 => "PC00015"
  2 => "PC00017"
]
```

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id IN (:client_ids)",
            array('client_ids'=>$client_ids)
           )
);
```

And the error is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id IN (:client_ids))
```

Comment: what about `->whereIn()`? have you tried it

Answer (score 1):

this will work for you.

```
$results = DB::table('clients')->whereIn('client_id', $client_ids)->get();
```